# I have exported a Mysql Database, and am having syntax issues importing to a newer version

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am trying to import a Mysql DB into a new instance on an updated domain. I am getting the below syntax error, I cant work out what is wrong and everythig I try isnt working.

can you help?

SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: 'pringlerfe'
-- -- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `adverts`
--
CREATE TABLE  `adverts` (

 `advers_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `advers_name` VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `advers_sqimg` VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `advers_squrl` VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `advers_towerimg` VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `advers_url` VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `advers_des` VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `advers_display` VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

--
-- Table struc' at line 3 `
```

Comment: is it something as silly as using ' instead of `?

Comment: It may well be.... Ill give it a go...

Comment: But the error is on the table structure line.. So it cant be..

Comment: Why not just lose the quotes ` and then execute?

Comment: strange that's a comment. Can't cause errors. or am I missing something?

Comment: may you share the command by which you are importing your .sql...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE  adverts (
 advers_id int NOT NULL,
 advers_name varchar( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL,
 advers_sqimg VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL,
 advers_squrl VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL,
 advers_towerimg VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL,
 advers_url VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL,
 advers_des VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL,
 advers_display VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT NULL
 );
```